# Red line showing in pom.xml in IntelliJ when project is imported

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I imported project in IntelliJ and then It downloaded all the dependency ,but it is still showing me red colour in pom.xml.

[image]

The red line it is showing me:

[image]

What is the problem in IntelliJ? How can I remove this red marker?

Comment: Try to execute `mvn clean compile`

Comment: right click on the project and select maven-> reimport

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, IntelliJ has this wired behavior. There are a few Solution to be taken

Execute following commands

```
mvn idea:clean
mvn idea:idea
mvn clean install
```

These 3 commands most probably solve dependency issues in IntelliJ. If it keeps failing clear Intellij Cache and restarts the application and try again with above commands

Answer (score 0):

Actually Maven external libraries will be imported on Maven -> Reimport context command.

Answer (score -1):

You are using the wrong groupId for common-lang.
Try this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

But better use the lates common-lang3:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.9</version>
</dependency>
```

You can check the lates versions in https://mvnrepository.com